# File::Path::make_path doesn't work on Windows with Unicode strings

Tags: perl

I tried to use the `make_path` to create the directory name which is UNICODE then in that case its giving error , but it works fine if the directory name is not unicode.

```
my $UTF16_dirname = encode("UTF-16LE", "$FormattedPath\0"); 

make_path($UTF16_dirname);
```

Comment: What platform? What value is `$FormattedPath`? What error do you get with `strict` and `warnings`?

Comment: What platform are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl has `mkdir` but no core `make_path`. I assume you mean the function provided by the [`File::Path`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Path) module?

Are you are using Windows? `File::Path::make_path` uses Perl's `mkdir` operator, which in turn uses the (deprecated) Windows POSIX `mkdir` call which doesn't support wide characters.

I recommend that you install the [`Win32::Unicode::Dir`](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32::Unicode::Dir) and use `mkpathW` which *does* support wide characters. There are some small issues with the installation tests, but it seems to work fine.

You should pass a simple string that uses Perl encoding. You don't need to `decode` anything, and `encode` is necessary only if you are reading data from a non-UTF-8 source. You also shouldn't be appending a trailing NUL character. You are writing in Perl, not in C.

Here is an example

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::Unicode::Dir 'mkpathW';

mkpathW './कार्तिक' or die $!;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer